# How to get the PYTHONPATH in shell?

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

```
debian@debian:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH  
/home/qiime/lib/:  
debian@debian:~$ python  
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07)   
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import sys  
>>> sys.path  
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py2.7.egg',   
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stripogram-1.5-py2.7.egg', '/home/qiime/lib', 
'/home/debian', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',   
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-
dynload',   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',  
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

How can I get all of `PYTHONPATH` output in bash?
Why  `echo  $PYTHONPATH` can not get all of them?

Comment: `sys.path` is not `PYTHONPATH`, `sys.path` actually consists of multiple things : current dir,PYTHONPATH,standard library, and paths contained in .pth files if any. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is actually only added to the list of locations Python searches for modules. You can print out the full list in the terminal like this:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

Or if want the output in the UNIX directory list style (separated by `:`) you can do this:

```
python -c "import sys; print(':'.join(x for x in sys.path if x))"
```

Which will output something like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py2.7.egg:/usr/local/lib/
python2.7/dist-packages/stripogram-1.5-py2.7.egg:/home/qiime/lib:/home/debian:/us
r/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib
/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib- dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL:/u
sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0:
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
```

Comment: Is sys path same as PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @variable No, the paths in `PYTHONPATH` is added to the paths in `sys.path` when the Python interpreter starts. In other words, `sys.path` will include all the paths in `PYTHONPATH`, but also additional paths, like the path to the Python standard library and the path to installed packages.

Comment: OK, Please can you advise how I can get the value of PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @variable In bash `echo $PYTHONPATH`, in Python 3 `import os; print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])`

Comment: This gives me syntax error (pointing to end of import word - EOL while scanning string literal): python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])'. If I use double quote then it says "name 'PYTHONPATH' is not defined"

Comment: @variable This works for me (Python 3): `PYTHONPATH=test python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])'`. If you're still having problems I'm in the [Python 3 chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). Let's not pollute the comment section here :)

Comment: slight mod to the original: PYTHONPATH=$(python -c "import os, sys; print(os.pathsep.join(x for x in sys.path if x))")

Comment: To make output more readable: `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['pythonpath'].replace(';', '\n'))"`

Answer (score 24):

### Just write:

just write `which python` in your terminal and you will see the python path you are using.

Comment: That's the path to the python executable NOT the PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH is where python itself looks for modules to import.

Comment: The path where Python itself exists is called PYTHON_HOME or PYTHONHOME

Comment: >>> which python
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    which python
          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Answer (score 15):

Those of us using Python 3.x should do this:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

Answer (score 9):

Python, at startup, loads a bunch of values into `sys.path` (which is "implemented" via a list of strings), including:

- various hardcoded places
- the value of `$PYTHONPATH`
- probably some stuff from startup files (I'm not sure if Python has `rcfiles`)

`$PYTHONPATH` is only one part of the eventual value of `sys.path`.

If you're after the value of `sys.path`, the best way would be to ask Python (thanks @Codemonkey):

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also try this:
Python 2.x:
`python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"`
Python 3.x:
`python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`

The output will be more readable and clean, like so:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC

Comment: Please notice that there is a typo in the second line of code. It should read 'python', not 'python3'.

Comment: @Pauli  not a typo.  One (old) convention is to install Python 2.7 as "python" and Python 3.x as "python3".

Answer (score 2):

Adding to ***@zzzzzzz*** answer, I ran the command:`python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and it provided me with different paths comparing to the same command with `python`. The paths that were displayed with `python3` were "python3 oriented".

See the output of the two different commands:

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

> ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

`python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

> ['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Both commands were executed on my **Ubuntu 18.04** machine.