# ImportError: cannot import name wraps on Mac

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pycharm

I am trying to run Python unit test using mock on IDE: PyCharm.

Since I am using Mac (El Capiton), I am unable to do:
`pip install mock`

Therefore I did:
`sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed six`
`sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed mock`

It installed successfully. Now when I write a test, it throws following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
import mock.mock as _mock
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 68, in <module>
from six import wraps
ImportError: cannot import name wraps
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Unistalled `mock 1.3.0` and installed `mock 1.0.1`. Since the latter does not depend on six, the issue got resolved!

Answer (score 3):

Mock requires [six version 1.7 or newer](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/blob/master/requirements.txt). `pip show six` to get the version and `pip install --upgrade six` to upgrade.

If that doesn't work, check which version of `six` is being loaded.

- Check the **Python Version**

  ```
  thomas:~$ python -c 'import six; print(six.__version__)'
  1.10.0
  ```
- Check the **pip Version** using `pip show six`

  ```
  thomas:~$ pip show six | grep ^Version
  Version: 1.10.0
  ```
- Check the **Python Location**

  ```
  thomas:~$ python -c 'import six; print(six.__file__)'
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six.pyc
  ```

Delete the python version and pip version are different, delete `six.py` and `six.pyc` from the **Python Location**

Sources:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417964/importerror-cannot-import-name-wraps)

[Github](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/298)

[Github](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/321)

Comment: I ran following on my terminal: `find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions -name six.py*`  And found: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/lib/six.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/lib/six.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc`. Which one should be deleted?

Comment: There's definitely an old version of `six`. Check `pip show six` and see where pip installed it. Whats your [python path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269941/6051898)? Use `python -c "import six; print six.__file__"` to see what version python is loading.

Comment: `pip show six` is showing `Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print sys.path` is returning:

`['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', ` ... and so on

Comment: What's actually being loaded? `python -c "import six; print six.__file__"`. If it's the same as `pip show six`, what's the version from `pip show six`. six version 1.10.0 is working for me. `pip install --upgrade six` to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that there is an old version of six (1.4.1) in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` and in `sys.path` this directory comes before `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` where the newer version of six is installed. This looks to me like a configuration issue of the python Apple provides.

The easiest solution I could come up with is setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable explicitly to include `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, so it ends up in `sys.path` before the `/System/...` path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

I suppose installing a correctly configured python in /usr/local would do the trick as well.